# automatic image scale based on aspect ratio

Tags: beamer, graphics, automation

i have a bunch of images in a folder (used to lighten-up lecture slides). currently, i change the images included by hand when updating the lecture slides. this requires to change either the width or the height of the image to match, say, `\textwidth` or `\textheight`. i'm wondering if there's an *automatic* way that would use the aspect ratio of an image to automatically decide if width or height should be manipulated.

i am also considering using a pseudo-random selection of images from that folder, which means that it will not matter if the aspect-ratio-based width-or-height decision is made on the fly or when pre-computing the list of images (with potentially additional information per image).

(hope this two part problem doesn't go against forum rules :)

Comment: you can set both width and height and use the key `keepaspectratio`. Beside this you can naturally measure a graphic before using it and set keys accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use adjustbox package to achieve this.

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % graphicx is also included
```

Then set both max width and max height whenever using includegraphics.

```
\includegraphics[max height=\textheight,max width=\textwidth]{image}
```

This maintains the aspect ratio and adjusts either height or width to the set parameters (\textheight and \textwidth in this case).

Answer (score 1):

As @ulrike-fischer said, you can use the options already available for the `\includegraphics` command. In particular, you need the `keepaspectratio` option.

For example, I typically use the command below when I want to fill most of a beamer frame with an image. This works for any image regardless of its aspect ratio or original size.

`\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight,keepaspectratio]{myfigurename}`